# Preferred way to convert openapi 3 document (json or yaml) to markdown, adoc or any other static format

Tags: java, openapi, swagger-3.0

I try to find an easy way in java to convert an openapi 3 document (json or yaml) in a static format like markdown, html or adoc. Searching around I've found a view projects like [Swagger2Markup](https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup), but they aren't ready for Openapi v3!

Does anyone have any advice or an hint for a library or maven plugin for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the correct maven plugin to do this:

```
<plugin>
    <!-- converts the openapi docu to html -->
    <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.35</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>export-opennapi-to-html-doc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
               <inputSpec>${project.build.directory}/api.yml</inputSpec>
               <language>html2</language>
               <output>${project.basedir}/docs</output>
             </configuration>
         </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check the project https://github.com/Mermade/widdershins
It is a good tool that converts from Openapi specs to markdown.
it is an npm module, and it is generating markdown to use on Redoc, but you can still customize the generated template